# Java Method for generating final variable NOT updating the value used for it

Tags: java, final

Hi I'm working with **JAVA by blueJ**
and I'm having problem with the code below:

```
public class License {

    private String lastName = "Null";
    private final String ID_NUM = generateIDNumber();
    private static int ID_GEN = 33333;

    public License(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName; 
    } 

    private String generateIDNumber() {
        String firstLetter = getLastName().substring(0,1);
        String idNumber = String.format("%d", ID_GEN) + "-" + firstLetter;                       firstLetter;
        ID_GEN += 1;
        return idNumber;
    }
}
```

So when I put my last name as an input, the program needs to generate the id number
which is composed of **5 digit number and first letter of the input last name.**

However, the value of `lastName` used for `generateIDNumber()`is **not getting updated with the newly entered input**,
although when I execute `getLastName()`, it gets the updated input.


In other words, even if I input the `lastName` as "James", the value of `firstLetter` in `generateIDNumber()` is still "33333-N" for "Null", not "33333-J" for "James".


Why is this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the code, you set the ID_NUM attribute at Class level (template level) and not at object level (completed after executes constructor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting `ID_NUM` before the constructor runs, so `lastName` is still `"Null"`. The solution is to set it within the constructor:

```
private final String ID_NUM;

public License(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.ID_NUM = generateIDNumber();
}
```

As a side note, CONSTANT_CASE should be reserved for `static final` variables. None of your variables fall into that category.